# Windows 8.1: How to tell power management to ONLY TURN SCREEN OFF when closing the lid?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, power-management, lid

I was expecting to find another option in my laptops power management when I close the lid, but all I found is those 3 options:

1. Do nothing
2. Sleep
3. Shut down

[image]

In an old ThinkPad running Windows 2000 I recall having a 4th option: **Turn screen off**.

Is there a way to accomplish that in a modern Lenovo laptop (model 2015) running Windows 8.1?

Comment: What happens if you click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**?

Comment: @DavidPostill If I click `Change settings that are currently unavailable` nothing that's relevant to turning off screen happens. All this does is un-gray-out `require password`, `sleep` in power menu and `lock` in picture menu options. Not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%208%20close%20lid%20black%20screen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=windows%208%20close%20lid%20turn%20screen%20off), [Yahoo answers for Windows 7](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100101112828AAJqjvc) which I tried on my Windows 8.1 laptop and verified it works:

`Do nothing` means "turn screen off when closing lid".